# Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, bundle

Please any help is very appreciated...

```
package sampleA_code2;
...
public class CodeTwoSample {
...
ResourceBundle greetings = ResourceBundle.getBundle("sampleA_code2.GoodMannersBundle");
```

Get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name sampleA_code2.GoodMannersBundle, locale en_IE
```

The file "GoodMannersBundle.properties" is in the same folder as "CodeTwoSample.java" is...

Please, any ideas?
Using Mac, NetBeans 12.6...
Tested with Java 11, Java 8....

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running from a .jar file?

Comment: Hey! No.. and all files under same package folder.. thanks

Comment: How are you running your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved the properties files to
src/main/resources

Also no need to reference the package anymore.
Thanks